# SRAM vs DRAM against single-event upsets

Tags: memory, ram, radiation

SRAM basically stores a bit in a flip-flop made of a few transistors, while DRAM stores a bit in a capacitor driven by a single transistor.

Would this mean that SRAM is less likely to face single-event upsets because it would require more energy to cause a bit flip, hence more reliable?

Comment: No. SRAM is less reliable by these means, as SEU is affecting logic circuits much more likely than changing a capacitor charge. Of course it can affect the DRAM controller..

Comment: except the sensitive point w.r.t. SEU and DRAM isn't the capacitor, it is the bitline

Comment: Well, doesn't the DRAM get read onto a cache before being utilized in the processor? Not sure what you are doing, but it seems like there is risk no matter how you structure your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The most significant factor is the physical (die) size of the transistor geometries (smaller means less SEU energy required to trigger them) and then the number of them (more devices/area = higher susceptibility).  So really, reliability per bit is more related to how many bits per silicon area.

If reliability is a concern, always include ECC and design the system & software for good error checking & graceful error handling.

Comment: I have an ECC controller on my CPU, does this suffice, or must I purchase RAM that explicitly mentions that it is ECC RAM?

Comment: You need ECC RAM as well.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of an SEU is tightly linked to the [Neutron Cross Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_cross_section) of a memory cell.

This determines the aperture for energetic free neutrons; the smaller it is, the less chance of an event.

It is interesting to note that smaller device geometries *do not* imply a higher sensitivity to SEUs; Xilinx has run a project for many years [measuring SEU rates](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1073_NSEU_Mitigation_Avionics.pdf) on their parts and [publish updates](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug116.pdf) twice a year.

The table for soft error rates from the current version is below:

[image: Xilinx SEU data]

Note that the 20nm node data shows a lower susceptibility than previous generations.

As noted, DRAM should be protected with ECC as should SRAM if possible.

GSI has been shipping SRAMs with [onboard ECC](http://gsitechnology.com/AppNotes/AN1024.pdf) for a while now, and beam testing at LANSCE shows no measurable errors, so the fault rate is < 1 FIT (FIT = Failure in Time, failures per billion device hours).

As to which is more susceptible; hard to say.

If your product is in an environment where such things are likely, then protecting it with ECC is the best thing to do.

Note that for old BGAs (with SnPb solder), the lead in the solder contains traces of Pb210, part of the [Uranium decay chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_chain) which has a decay pah through Po210 (Polonium) which is an alpha emitter; alpha particles are big and can [easily cause SEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error) events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with you that a SEU is more likey on DRAM than SRAM.
The reason is that SRAM memory is regenerated natively by the back to back inverters.  If ionizing radiation significantly changes the amount of charge on a node, assuming it does not completely flip the bit, it will be restored to normal levels quite quickly by either the feedforward or feedback inverter.

In DRAM, the memory is stored on a capacitor.  This capacitor is made as small as feasibly possible w.r.t leakage and refresh required to reduce the power consumption and create a smaller area footprint for the DRAM bitcell.  Since this capacitance is generally made as small as possible, a lesser amount of charge will create more of a voltage change on the capacitor, since Q = CV.

On top of that, the DRAM is not immediately regenerated due to the nature of back to back inverters (like the SRAM cell is).  This means any change of voltage on the cap is permanent until either a refresh/read/write occurs.

Another user mentioned that in SRAM is the wordlines which would in actuality be what caused problems.  I disagree.  These word lines have HUGE capacitances compared to the capacitance either in a SRAM or DRAM cell.  This makes a SEU actually changing the logic level very unlikely since again, Q = CV, so a very large C means a smaller change in voltage for the same amount of charge.  It also has greater area so you could argue it would encounter more ionizing particles.  But by definition this is not a "single-event upset" (implying a single ionizing particle).